# Can't load static resource with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

In my multi-module spring boot project I have included thymeleaf in the *bo_ui* module to show html pages.

Below what has been done so far.

MVC configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "com.cmw.bo.console" })
/**
 * Java configuration file that is used for Spring MVC and Thymeleaf
 * configurations
 */
public class WebMVCConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer,  ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.addPathPrefix("/ui", HandlerTypePredicate.forBasePackage("com.cmw.ui"))
//                  .addPathPrefix("/basis", HandlerTypePredicate.forBasePackage("com.cmw.basis"))
                  .addPathPrefix("/api", HandlerTypePredicate.forBasePackage("com.cmw.api"));
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver htmlViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine(htmlTemplateResolver()));
        resolver.setContentType("text/html");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setViewNames(ArrayUtil.array("*.html"));
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver javascriptViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine(javascriptTemplateResolver()));
        resolver.setContentType("application/javascript");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setViewNames(ArrayUtil.array("*.js"));
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver plainViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine(plainTemplateResolver()));
        resolver.setContentType("text/plain");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setViewNames(ArrayUtil.array("*.txt"));
        return resolver;
    }

    private ISpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(ITemplateResolver templateResolver) {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect(new GroupingStrategy()));
        engine.addDialect(new Java8TimeDialect());
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        engine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(messageSource());
        return engine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        resolver.setOrder(0);
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return resolver;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver javascriptTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/public/js/");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.JAVASCRIPT);
        return resolver;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver plainTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/txt/");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Spring Message Resolver")
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("it"));
        return localeResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    @Description("Custom Conversion Service")
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addFormatter(new NameFormatter());
    }
    
}
```

Thymeleaf dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

testPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>my test</title>
    <script th:src="@{/public/js/test.js}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>this is a test page</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

resources folder of the project:

[image]

When I try to reach the testPage.html through my endpoint, the page loads correctly, but inspecting the elements I see a 404 error on test.js.

I tried on both the *public* folder and the *static* folder.

Looking at the springboot logs I see:

```
2022-03-18 16:10:27.372 DEBUG 8940 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /public/js/test.js
2022-03-18 16:10:27.375  WARN 8940 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /public/js/test.js
```

So I suppose there is also a problem at the springsecurity level. Here is the configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String REMEMBER_ME_INTERNAL_SHARED_KEY = "f1406c2dfghdfghf-26e3-dfgh45ed-8dfgh19c-dfgh4131cadaa431";

    private static final String REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE_NAME = "cmw-session-id";
    private static final String SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = "JSESSIONID";

    @Autowired
    private OperatorsAuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("basisDataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;


    @Bean
    public static RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy() {

        RoleHierarchyImpl hierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
        hierarchy.setHierarchy(

                "ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_MANAGER\n" +
                        "ROLE_MANAGER > ROLE_HELPDESK\n" +
                        "ROLE_HELPDESK > ROLE_MARKETING\n" +
                        "ROLE_MARKETING > ROLE_OPERATOR\n" +
                        "ROLE_OPERATOR > ROLE_USER"
        );

        return hierarchy;
    }



    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/static**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/public**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/basis/otp/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/basis/customers/1").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/basis/customers/3").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/basis/profiles/**/chpass/otp/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/basis/operators/chpass/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "MANAGER", "HELPDESK", "MARKETING", "OPERATOR")
//                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager())
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())
                .key(REMEMBER_ME_INTERNAL_SHARED_KEY)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies(REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE_NAME, SESSION_COOKIE_NAME)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .invalidSessionUrl("/login");
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {

        return new AuthenticationProviderImpl();
    }

//    @Bean
//    public AuthenticationProvider googleAuthenticationProvider() {
//
//        return new GoogleAuthenticationProviderImpl();
//    }

    @Bean
    public RememberMeServices rememberMeServices() {

        PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices services = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(REMEMBER_ME_INTERNAL_SHARED_KEY,
                authenticationService, tokenRepository());
        services.setAlwaysRemember(true);
        services.setTokenValiditySeconds(432000);
        services.setCookieName(REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE_NAME);
        services.setParameter("remember-me");

        return services;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository tokenRepository() {

        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepository = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        tokenRepository.setDataSource(dataSource);
        tokenRepository.setCreateTableOnStartup(false); // Set to false in production

        return tokenRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler webSecurityExpressionHandler() {

        DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy());

        return expressionHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebExpressionVoter webExpressionVoter() {

        WebExpressionVoter webExpressionVoter = new WebExpressionVoter();
        webExpressionVoter.setExpressionHandler(webSecurityExpressionHandler());

        return webExpressionVoter;
    }

    @Bean
    public RoleHierarchyVoter roleHierarchyVoter() {

        return new RoleHierarchyVoter(roleHierarchy());
    }

    @Bean
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AffirmativeBased accessDecisionManager() {

        List<AccessDecisionVoter<?>> voters = new ArrayList<>();
        voters.add(roleHierarchyVoter());
        voters.add(webExpressionVoter());

        return new AffirmativeBased(voters);
    }

    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {

        Map<String, String> exceptionMappings = new HashMap<>();

        exceptionMappings.put(InternalAuthenticationServiceException.class.getCanonicalName(), "/login?error=serverError");
        exceptionMappings.put(AuthenticationServiceException.class.getCanonicalName(), "/login?error=serverError");
        exceptionMappings.put(BadCredentialsException.class.getCanonicalName(), "/login?error=authfailed");
        exceptionMappings.put(DisabledException.class.getCanonicalName(), "/login?error=disabled");
        exceptionMappings.put(UsernameNotFoundException.class.getCanonicalName(), "/login?error=usernameNotFound");
        exceptionMappings.put(CredentialsExpiredException.class.getCanonicalName(), "/login?error=usernameNotFound");
        exceptionMappings.put(AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException.class.getCanonicalName(), "/login?error=usernameNotFound");

        exceptionMappings.put(UsernameCredentialsExpiredException.class.getCanonicalName(), "/basis/operators/chpass");

        final UsernameCachingExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler result = new UsernameCachingExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler();
        result.setExceptionMappings(exceptionMappings);
        result.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?error=default");

        return result;
    }

}
```

I have tried several configurations but without success.

Anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: seem like you use spring security? have you protected some page?

Comment: Yes, I' m using spring security but the page i'm requesting is marked as permitAll. (See endpoint /basis/customers/3 in WebSecurityConfig)

Answer (score 0):

Check your public.js directory name. You want to reach public/js/test.js and is not exist! I am not sure that is a main problem but it can help.